# Print nozzle too far from the plate

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, bed-leveling, z-axis

My son has a Creality Ender 3 S1. It had been printing fine until this morning. The nozzle is about 3 mm (1/8 inch) from the build plate. Is there a "reset" or "calibration" function I'm missing in the menu?

Comment: Just a quick check - I think that the S1 should have an Automatic Bed Levelling (ABL) probe, does yours have one? Also, have you read the manual or user guide? At least some of the answers seem to be easily found there. If you have, and those steps don't work for you, then please [edit] and update your question, to explain *why* the steps in the manual do not work for you.

Answer (score 2):

##### TL;DR

There *should* be both a "Restore factory defaults" setting and an "ABL setup" setting in the touch screen UI.

---

##### Bed level

From section **6 - Auto leveling** of the [user guide](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2602827/Ender-Ender-3-S1-Pro.html?page=13#manual):

> Go to "settings" and tap "leveling" to enter the CR Touch leveling interface. Tap "start" and wait for the automatic leveling to complete.

Section 7 covers "Assisted Leveling" or manual leveling.

##### Factory Reset

***Inexplicably***, this isn't in the User Guide, but from [How do you factory reset an ender 3 S1 pro?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ender3S1/comments/11qv7vo/how_do_you_factory_reset_an_ender_3_s1_pro/):

> Settings > ADV SET. > Restore All Set.

---

#### Still having issues?

I can't give a verified answer, but there *seems* to be a common-ish issue<sup>1</sup>, after having done a bit of googling.

I assume that your S1 has a Automatic Bed Levelling (ABL) probe.

From Reddit - [Bed Leveling problem on my new ENder 3 S1 pro - ABL doesnt seems to compensate well](https://www.reddit.com/r/ender3/comments/u69d57/bed_leveling_problem_on_my_new_ender_3_s1_pro_abl/), there are at least three potential solutions (copied verbatim with no corrected typos):

> Make sure there is no clog in the nozzle or throat. that is not the fix but i did have problems with clicking and that fixed it. you only need to run the Auto level once. the Auto level on these machine are garbage. after the auto level adjust the z offset with the paper USING the touch screen adjustment. then go to all four corners with the paper at least twice using the knobs under the bed, not the touch screen adjustment, to get it dialed in. DO NOT run the Auto level again after this. if your g code is set to tell the machine to auto level before or after printer, Disable this. It should print fine until you do an auto level again. also make sure the bed is super clean. We are stuck with non working fancy stuff on these printers until someone can save the day with nice firmware changes, except for people like me who have the crap chip that wont let you flash at all  Sorry for any run on sentences. Also do the manual bed level with the bed warmed up not cold. my machine will crash the software if i try to auto level warm, so i have to heat it up and turn on off the bed

or

> 1. Loosen all Axis just to the point of a tiny bit slop.
> 2. Clear settings(factory reset)
> 3. Manual level with paper all four coners and 80c
> 4. Run ABL
> 5. Be happy with your printer again.

or

> - Reset to factory defaults
> - Iniciate leveling throught settings
> - Wait for the Home routine
> - Using the point 1, I adjust the z-offset using the paper metod
> - Cicle all corners (using the touch menu) and adjust the bed height using the knobs until all have the same resistance. Do not return to the first point in this step
> - Return to the point 1 and set the z-offset to zero.
> - Run the ABL and wait.
> - Return to home screen using the top left arrow.
> - Run a first layer test and adjust the z-offset.
> - Done

---

<sup>1</sup> Which may or may not be a bug in the firmware